# Use Guid as ID in MongoDb for C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

I'm trying to use Guid datatype as Id in my Poco object "Parameter". However, while I'm able to write files to the database I can't read from it.

This is the import function writing table headers from a csv file into the database. First line of the csv file are parameters and second line the units those parameters are measured in. All other lines contain actual values and are stored in another collection as BsonDocument. The csv files are dynamic and need to be selectable via combobox, which is why the parameters are written in their own collection.

```
IMongoCollection<Parameter> parameterCollection = this.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Parameter>("Parameters");
columnNames.Select((columnName, index) => new Parameter() { Name = columnName, Unit = columnUnits[index] })
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(parameter =>
           {
               parameterCollection.UpdateOne(Builders<Parameter>.Filter.Eq("Name", parameter.Name),
                                             Builders<Parameter>.Update.Set("Unit", parameter.Unit),
                                             new UpdateOptions()
                                             {
                                                 IsUpsert = true
                                             });
            });
```

This is the Parameter class:

```
public class Parameter
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the method trying to read the data from the document:

```
public List<Parameter> GetParameters()
{
    return this.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Parameter>("Parameters")
                             .Find(Builders<Parameter>.Filter.Empty)
                             .ToList();
}
```

This results in the following error message:

"**SystemFormatException:** 'An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class TimeSeriesInterface.DTO.Parameter: Cannot deserialize a 'Guid' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.'

I also tried this attribute: `[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]`

I'm unable to find any help besides those two attributes. They seem to solve it for everybody else, but I still keep getting this error.

I may add that the import and read functions are parts of different classes each calling their own `new MongoClient().GetDatabase(MongoDatabaseRepository.DatabaseName);` but when I use ObjectId as data type I do get the data so I don't think that's the issue.

Why not use ObjectId as data type? We have an extra project for database access and I do not wish to add the mongodb assembly all over the place just because other projects use the POCOs and require a reference for that pesky little ObjectId.

**EDIT:**

This is the mapping used within the constructor after suggestion by AlexeyBogdan (beforehand it was simply the call to AutoMap()):

```
public MongoDatabaseRepository(string connectionString)
{
    this.MongoDbClient = new MongoClient();
    this.MongoDatabase = this.MongoDbClient.GetDatabase(MongoDatabaseRepository.DatabaseName);

    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter>(parameterMap =>
    {
        parameterMap.AutoMap();
        parameterMap.MapIdMember(parameter => parameter.Id);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to post a minimum viable testable solution to get a better solution. However, I don't see any issue with DTO class and able to insert a sample document without any issue.

```
    var parameterCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Parameter>("Parameters");
    parameterCollection.InsertOne(
       new Parameter {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Document", Unit = "01"});
```

Comment: As I mentioned, inserting works fine. The problem only occurs when I try to read the collection. The ToList() method throws the exception.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher the question was asked long time ago, but it's still unanswered. Did you resolve described issue? Tried to reproduce it, but it works fine both on reading and writing after marking Guid property with BsonId attribute (version 2.9.3 of MongoDb.Driver)

Comment: @PetrPokrovskiy Switched my job. Can't actually remember whether I resolved it but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[BsonId]` I recommend you to use this mapping

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Type>(cm =>
  {
   cm.AutoMap();
   cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id);
  });
```

I Hope it helps you.

Comment: No, unfortunately I still receive the same error. With and without the Attributes.

Comment: `
public List<Parameter> GetParameters()
{
    return this.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Parameter>("Parameters")
                             .Find(_ => true)
                             .ToList();
}
`